# Async for loop behaviour behaves differently between map and [].push

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I was trying various exercises around await async and found and odd behaviour I can't explain between looping through a map vs array

With map:

```
async function loadFiles(files) {
var prs = files.map(getFile);
  for (let pr of prs) {
    console.log(await pr);
  }
}
```

With array push:

```
async function loadFiles(files) {
  let prs = [];
  files.forEach(file => {
    prs.push(getFile(file));
  });
  for (let pr in prs) {
    console.log(await prs[pr]);
  }
}
```

Now both give me the same results
I can't understand why in the case of pushing to an array, pr is the index of the array
but with the map it is directly the promise result

they are both array of promises, what is making them behave differently in the for ?

rest of the code:

```
function getFile(file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    fakeAjax(file, resolve);
  });
}

loadFiles(["file1", "file2", "file3"]);

// **************************************

function fakeAjax(url, cb) {
  var fake_responses = {
    file1: "The first text",
    file2: "The middle text",
    file3: "The last text"
  };
  var randomDelay = (Math.round(Math.random() * 1e4) % 8000) + 1000;

  console.log("Requesting: " + url);

  setTimeout(function() {
    cb(fake_responses[url]);
  }, randomDelay);
}
```

Comment: Unlessed I've missed something, the second snippet is just a rather long-winded way to do exactly the same thing as the first. The `forEach` does the same as the `map` in the first snippet, and the loop is the same, accounting for the fact that the first is a `for ... of` while the second is a `for ... in`. I'm not quite sure where your confusion lies. [And while this seems to be a question about promises and async/await, that aspect of the code is identical between both functions.]

Comment: yep they should do the same thing. (When I come across a new shorthand, I always make an exercise of writing it in an expanded way to see what pattern I'm replacing, helps me learn :) )
As josh and yourself pointed out I didn't see I had used `for ... in` in the second example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference you're seeing is the difference between `for ... of` and `for ... in`.

`for ... of` iterates over the *values* in a collection like an Array. You will get the actual `Promise` objects.

`for ... in` iterates over the enumerable *properties* of an object, in this case, the properties 0, 1, 2... of the Array.

Comment: I was so focued on promises and map that I didn't even see that I had put `in` instead of `of` now the world (of for loops) makes sense again

Comment: It happens! That's why I try to use `.forEach` over `for ... of` when possible.